# Is this a chili disease or just bad treatment?

Tags: diseases, chili

Some days ago I found out that my chillies had some kind of small worms-looking things. Probably thrips or something else. And I had some kind of flies.

I sprayed them with soapwater. Some of the plants did not like this however.
After that I added also added fertilizer, since some of they looked like it was time to get it.

**So now I wounder, are all these spots consequences of all up and down last week, or could this be some kind of virus?  "Bacterial leaf spot"?**

24th of April, looking really good:
 [image: 24th of April]

Then the 4th of May I sprayed them, after I had sprayed the plants:
[image: Plants after spray]
The top of the plant turns black, the leaves get just sad, dries/curls and dies.
[image: top of the plant]

The fly, which has decreased
[image: Flie]

**Plants 10th of May**
Same plant as on the second picture, to the right
[image: Plant]

Spots on leaves

[image: Spots on leaves]

Another with spots

[image]

Apache plant from last year. Picture taken 5th of May. Removed the dead leaves. This plant seems to have recovered now a week later
[image: Plant from last year]

Comment: Next time just remove the "small worm looking things" by hand.

Comment: @Rob I felt there were several and wanted to kill them all. But I have removed them by hand now afterwards. Now I have only found them on my tomato plants and not so many of them.

Comment: If you are going to use an insecticide use a neonicotinoid and not soap.

Comment: @Rob isn't that what they think is the cause to massive bee death?

Comment: Only the ignorant masses think that. If you want to educate yourself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtACFGJ62zU

Comment: Thanks. My biggest concern now is if I need to throw some plant away if any of them is infected.

Comment: Imho, this is a reaction to the use of soapy water and not an infection or a reaction to the bugs.

Comment: @Rob - Lin Field is a shill for Bayer. Do some research and educate yourself: https://media.bayer.com/baynews/baynews.nsf/id/Bayer-and-Rothamsted-Research-sign-strategic-framework-agreement  Personally, I think that neonics for airborne-pollinated plants is probably not a problem, but peppers are insect-pollinated. Even the US has indicated that neonics hurt pollinators (but good luck finding that on an EPA website);.

Comment: @Jurp Let me ask you a question. If you were in her position would you sacrifice your morals and ethics? Why are you assuming that because she get's paid that automatically means she's a completely garbage human being who has no filter on what she's willing to do and say for money? When and where did she lie in that video?

Comment: I'm not saying she's a garbage human being at all, but her close association with Bayer makes everything she says on the subject of pesticides suspect - one does NOT want to bite the hand that feeds one. Of course she'll "toe the party line", or she'll lose a ton of funding. If the video predates the alliance with Bayer - so what? Bayer knows that they have a compliant mouthpiece for their propaganda. This worked great against climate change in the US, didn't it? Personally, I do not use pesticides on anything I eat that I grow, as a matter of personal safety, but do use herbicides at times.